# Questions about Doctype

Tags: html, doctype, strict, transitional

I started working on a project and forgot to mention the DOCTYPE at the beginning and just used `<html>`. I feel really stupid about doing it, right now. The webpage heavily realizes on javascript and I have a lot of instances of the document height and scrollTop. Now I just realized that and added a Doctype. This messed up the whole page. I tried transitional and strict, but all the doctypes have the same effect.
My question is if the default doctype is always`<!DOCTYPE html>`? I read online that if no doctype is specified it always resorts to `<!DOCTYPE html>`. I tried changing it to that, but it still messes up the website. So could

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because you are using elements that are associated with a specific DOCTYPE. `<!DOCTYPE html>` defaults to html5. If no DOCTYPE is specified, you webpage defaults to quirks mode. Since you set everything up according to this standard, it isn't compatible with a standard mode.

Comment: Thanks I realized that if I used transitional without a identifier it should use quirks instead of standard.